# Post-hoc test for binomial GLM with some cases having probabilities of 1

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, post-hoc

I am studying the effect of plant survival on location and genotype. I fitted a binomial GLM and conducted a post-hoc test after significant interaction using the `emmeans` package. When survival was 100%, i.e. no mortality whatsoever, the lower and upper confidence limits extended all the way from 0 to 1 and were not significantly different from the other survival probabilities:

```
m1 <- glm(cbind(totalalive, totaldead) ~ f1 * f2,  family = binomial, df)
summary(m1)

#Call:
#glm(formula = cbind(totalalive, totaldead) ~ f1 * f2, family = binomial, 
#    data = df)
#
#Deviance Residuals: 
#     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
#-2.94105   0.00011   0.00011   0.78201   1.68444  
#
#Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#(Intercept)  2.092e+01  2.371e+03   0.009    0.993
#f1B          2.002e-08  3.353e+03   0.000    1.000
#f1C         -1.655e+01  2.371e+03  -0.007    0.994
#f2V2         2.032e-08  3.353e+03   0.000    1.000
#f2V3        -1.858e+01  2.371e+03  -0.008    0.994
#f1B:f2V2    -1.928e+01  4.106e+03  -0.005    0.996
#f1C:f2V2    -2.730e+00  3.353e+03  -0.001    0.999
#f1B:f2V3     3.635e-01  3.353e+03   0.000    1.000
#f1C:f2V3     1.746e+01  2.371e+03   0.007    0.994
#
#(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#
#    Null deviance: 137.380  on 89  degrees of freedom
#Residual deviance:  80.419  on 81  degrees of freedom
#AIC: 148.99
#
#Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

To conduct a post-hoc test, I used the `emmeans()` function of the `emmeans` package:

```
cld(emmeans(m1, ~f1 : f2), type="response", Letters = letters, adjust = "none")

 #f1 f2   prob           SE  df    asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group
 #C  V2 0.8375 4.124527e-02 Inf 7.399573e-01 0.9032387  a    
 #B  V2 0.8375 4.124527e-02 Inf 7.399573e-01 0.9032387  a    
 #A  V3 0.9125 3.159188e-02 Inf 8.276478e-01 0.9577123  ab   
 #B  V3 0.9375 2.706329e-02 Inf 8.584872e-01 0.9737457  ab   
 #C  V3 0.9625 2.124081e-02 Inf 8.901011e-01 0.9878549   b   
 #C  V1 0.9875 1.242163e-02 Inf 9.166073e-01 0.9982419   b   
 #A  V1 1.0000 1.939592e-06 Inf 2.220446e-16 1.0000000  ab   
 #B  V1 1.0000 1.939592e-06 Inf 2.220446e-16 1.0000000  ab   
 #A  V2 1.0000 1.939592e-06 Inf 2.220446e-16 1.0000000  ab
```

And here is a plot of the results:

[image]

As can be seen by the lower and upper confidence limits, the instances with 100% survival are not significantly different from the other groups. I am sure the reason for this is that there is no variation in those cases with 100% survival (standard error is effectively zero) and it is not possible to test whether they are significantly different to the others.

Is this correct? If that's the case, would it be:

**(a)** reasonable to remove the letters from those cases with 100% survival and test for significant differences only on those cases where the probability of survival is $<1$?

Or **(b)** should I leave the significance letters in the plot and just simply explain it in the figure caption as I did above?

At this point (see figure above) it may look strange to the reader how `SiteC - GenotypeV2` can be different from `SiteC - GenotypeV1` but `SiteB - GenotypeV2` is not different from `SiteB - GenotypeV1`.

## EDIT

For clarification, I also added a boxplot of the raw data to illustrate this. The number of replicates is 10 per factor combination:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you just don't have enough information at site A for genotypes V1 and V2 to estimate the survival probabilities, which translates into a lot of uncertainty? Not sure what you are measuring for each site and genotype combination, but perhaps start by looking at how many of those things you are measuring (where each thing gives you values for totalalive and totaldead) at A - V1 and A - V2 versus A - V3, B - V1, ..., C - V3. Are you measuring much fewer things (where things might be sets of trials) at A - V1 and A - V2 compared to all other site by genotype combinations?

Comment: Additionally, you could also compute the observed survival proportions total alive/(total alive + total dead) for all things you kept track of at A - V1 and A - V2 relative to everything else. You can then plot these observed proportions using a dotplot to see how variable they are within A - V1 and A - V2 relative to all other site by genotype combinations.  These two things - how many things you measured and how variable were the observed survival proportions for these things at A - V1 and A - V2 relative to all else - should give you a better idea of the source of the large uncertainty.

Comment: Usually, a post-hoc test requires an adjustment for multiplicity given that you are looking at multiple pairwise comparisons? Any reason why no adjustment was made?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement It looks like I wasn't describing it well enough so I added a boxplot to better illustrate my point. For some factor combination I have 100 % survival, i.e. all genotypes planted at a given site survived.This will also lead to a standard error of 0. Now one could think that therefore the 100% surviors should be significantly different to all the other ones, however they are not and that is (I think) because there is no variation associated with the 100% survival rate (SE = 0) and therefore the it is not possible to test whether they are different from the others [...]

Comment: [...] Therefore I was thinking removing the letters from those cases with 100% survival, since a comparison cannot be made anyway. At this point it looks irritating to the reader how for  SiteC GenotypeV2 can be different from GenotypeV1 but for SiteB GenotypeV2 is not different from GenotypeV1. Also, the reason why is didn't adjust for multiplicity was to exactly show this difference in the graph. IN reality I have some all Tukey adjusted.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, Stefan! The boxplots are very informative - you could add the number of replicates (r = 10) underneath each box - close to the horizontal axis-  and include that figure along with your multiple comparisons one when presenting findings to others.

Comment: Note that you are incorrectly concluding "there are no differences" in survival probabilities between conditions when all your data are saying is that "there is no evidence of a difference".

Comment: Can I ask you for one more edit to your post? If you type options(scipen= 999) in the R console and then rerun your emmeans command, the lower bounds of the confidence intervals should be easier to read. Also, can you clarify what the letters a, b and ab are supposed to mean in the emmeans output? Thanks!

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Thank you for all the edit suggestion but I think my problem should be clear now. Should I (a) exclude cases where 100% survival is observed from the GLM since they do not exhibit any variation whatsoever, or should I keep them in the analysis and note that they cannot be significantly different from one another to anyone else because they have no inherent variation.

Comment: I do not use emmeans so I wanted to make sure I understand what the letter notation stands for and also to see the actual values of the lower confidence limits. If others can respond without this information, good for them!

Comment: you're probably having a complete separation problem. Try `install.packages("brglm2"); library(brglm2); m1 <- glm(cbind(totalalive,totaldead) ~ f1 * f2,  family = binomial, df, method=brglmFit)` and going from there ...

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker ! That's works perfectly fine now. Would you mind providing this as an answer and perhaps a short explanation what the "complete separation problem" is? Then I would be happy to accept that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Complete separation** occurs in logistic (and binomial, and Poisson) regression when some categories contain 100% failures (or zero counts) or (in the logistic/binomial cases) 100% successes. In this case, the 'true' estimates are infinite (because logistic regression parameters are estimated on the logit scale, and logit(0) $\to -\infty$ while logit(1) $\to \infty$). Logistic regression typically leads to extreme (but not infinite) values of the parameter estimates, e.g. $|\hat \beta| > 8$. Worse, the usual Wald standard errors also tend to be very large, because the approximation of a quadratic log-likelihood surface that the Wald SEs depend on is very bad.

There's more explanation of complete separation [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/).

A reasonable solution is *Firth* or *bias-reduced* logistic regression, implemented in R's `brglm2` package as follows:

```
## install.packages("brglm2")
library(brglm2)
m1 <- glm(cbind(totalalive,totaldead) ~ f1 * f2, 
    family = binomial, df, method=brglmFit)
```